# Setting Foreign key params Relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship, foreign-key-relationship

I've searched a lot , found similar questions , but any seem to fit , or i did not understood right.

i have 3 models , i choose a bad name for one model, that is for Tv Shows , and you may confuse the Show model with show method and view .

**Show.rb**

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :seasons
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :episodes , through: :seasons
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons

    attr_accessible :name,:status,:duration
end
```

**Season.rb**

```
class Season < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :show
    has_many :episodes

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :episodes
    attr_accessible :order,:status
end
```

**Episode.rb**

```
class Episode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :season
    attr_accessible :number
end
```

My forms for each model are separeted, what i wanna do is set the foreigns keys for each one automatically. So , in the view of my Show i wanna create a season that will be stored in that Show.

**Shows/show.html.erb**

```
p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<% @seasons = Season.all %>
<% @episodes= Episode.all%>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @show.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Status:</strong>
  <%= @show.status %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Episode Duration:</strong>
  <%= @show.Episode_Duration %>
</p>


    <% @seasons.where(:show_id => @show.id).each do |season| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= season.order %></td>
        <td><%= season.status %></td>
        <h3>episodios</h3>
        <hr>
        <% @episodes.where(:season_id => season.id).each do |episode| %>
          <td> <%= episode.number%></td>
        <%end%>
        <hr>
        <td><%= link_to 'episode', episode_new_path(season.id)%></td>
      </tr>
      <br>
    <% end %>

    <h1><%=@show.id%></h1>
    <h1><%=@show.episodes.count%></h1>
    <h1></h1>




    **<%= link_to 'create seasons', season_new_path(@show.id)   %>**
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_show_path(@show) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', shows_path %>
```

In that lasts line, i'm passing @show.id for create a season, i want use that @show.id as my foreign key :show_id for that season. how i use that id in my params?

I saw some posts and i tried this , but didn't worked , heres the controller(only the part that i think is useful.)
**seasons_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @season = Season.new(season_params)
    @season.show_id = params[:id]
    @season.save
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @season.save
        format.html { redirect_to @season, notice: 'Season was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @season }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @season.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }

    end
  end

def season_params
      params.require(:season).permit(:order, :status)
    end
```

**EDIT**
My routes are: 
**Routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users
  resources :episodes

  resources :seasons

  resources :shows
  root 'shows#index'
  get 'seasons/create/:id' => 'seasons#new', as: :season_new
  get 'episodes/create/:id' => 'episodes#new', as: :episode_new

  put 'subscribe_show/:id' => 'shows#subscribe', as: :user_subscribe_show
  put 'unsubscribe_show/:id' => 'shows#unsubscribe', as: :user_unsubscribe_show

  get 'user/dashboard/' => 'users#index', as: :user_dashboard
```

And my forms are:
**seasons/form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@season) do |f| %>
  <% if @season.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@season.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this season from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @season.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :order %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :order %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Show/form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(@show) do |f| %>
  <% if @show.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@show.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this show from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @show.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Episode_Duration %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :Episode_Duration %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT 2:
**schema.rb**

```
create_table "episodes", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "number"
    t.integer  "season_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "seasons", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "order"
    t.string   "status"
    t.integer  "show_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean  "watched"
  end

  create_table "shows", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "status"
    t.datetime "created_at",       null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
    t.integer  "Episode_Duration"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end
```

**Migrations**

```
class AddUserIdtoShow < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    add_index  :shows , :user_id
  end
end
```

Comment: season_new_path should be for a form view where you submit the form to season_controller#create.   Where is this form?

Comment: added my forms and routes, is there anything more ?

Comment: Yep, where are your create_table migrations. Specifically I am looking for the t.belongs_to column declaration in seasons and episodes.

Comment: Added my schema.rb and one migration